# iterating through a json object while matching its key-value with a pattern in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Reading through a json object and matching it with a pattern using regular expresion. when the pattern match is found calling a function to create an user account else calling another function which just prints the existing user account details.

Used `for...in` loop to iterate through json object which is stored in a json file, though only one pattern value is passed to match with json object and either new account function should be created or existing account details should be printed. Yet it will check both true & false case and try to execute both functions which results in error.

How Can I iterate through json object from a file and just execute one case either true or false depending on the pattern match.

test.json

```
"PatternToSearch": {
    "generalPatterToSearch" : "gen",
    "facebookPattern"       : "Facebook",
    "mediaPattern"          : "^0--media"
  }
```

My code:

```
var patternToMatch = '0--media--121212';
var test = require('./test.json');

for (var key in test.PatternToSearch) {
  if (test.PatternToSearch.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    var value = test.PatternToSearch[key];
    var pattern = new RegExp(value);
    var isPattern = pattern.test(patternToMatch);
    if (!isPattern) {
      return function // create new account
    } else {
      return function // prints existing account details
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Didn't get you quite right here. Do you want to continue the pattern match until `isPattern` becomes `true`? Or you just want to return the functions based on the first value `isPattern` gets?

Comment: just want to return the function based on the first true value `isPattern` gets as `pattern` matches with `patternToMatch`. Currently it is executing both functions as atleast once the pattern would match and in other cases it will go to `!isPattern` case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood, you want to continue matching until a pattern is matched. If match is found, you want to return the function to create account. If no match is found, you want to return the function to print the values.

If the above is right, the problems is that you're returning in both the cases, i.e. whether the match is found or not found. `return` terminates the loop, and that's why it is buggy.

If the match is not found, you need to return after the loop completes:

```
for (var key in test.PatternToSearch) {
  if (test.PatternToSearch.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    var value = test.PatternToSearch[key];
    var pattern = new RegExp(value);
    var isPattern = pattern.test(patternToMatch);

    if (isPattern) {
      return function // create new account
    }
  }
}

return function // prints existing account details
```

Using `for...of` and `Object.values`, the above can be further minimized to this:

```
for (let value of Object.values(test.PatternToSearch)) {
   const pattern = new RegExp(value);

   if (pattern.test(patternToMatch)) {
     return function // create new account
   }
}

return function // prints existing account details
```